# this is undefined in devtools even if this is not undefined

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, google-chrome-devtools, aurelia, es6-class

[image: this is undefined in console]
"this" is undefined in devtool console while it is clearly not undefined.
Must be a bug in devtools?

Comment: yes, more os less... I don't know how to explain exactly... The problem is that the code you are "inspecting" is actually ECMAScript 5 but the code you are "seeing" is ES6. When you type `this` in the console, the browser tries to show the `this` variable, but in the souce-code there is no `this` variable, the transpiler usually uses `_this`... Instead of inspecting `this` try `_this` and you will see the correct value

Comment: Thanks, You are correct. The only difference is that in my case it looks like it is _this2

Comment: Yeah, it depends on several things... Take a look at the transpiled code (ES5) to see the real names of the variables

Comment: Try selecting `this` (doubleclick it), then rightclick and choose `Evaluate in console`. Maybe it's smart enough.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Value of "this" is incorrect when debugging Babel transpiled React with Chrome Devtools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36638663/value-of-this-is-incorrect-when-debugging-babel-transpiled-react-with-chrome-d)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are inspecting ES6/ES2015+ code (thanks to source-maps) and not the *actual code* which is in less readable ES5-transpiled code, the `this` property is not the same as what you see in the source code.

To access `this`, try evaluating `_this`, `_this1`, `_this2` and so forth in the console to find the context you are looking for.

```
const loaded = () => {
  this.setState({ loading: false });
};

// will be compiled/transpiled to

var _this = this;
var loaded = function loaded() {
  _this.setState({ loading: false });
};
```

Reference: https://www.sitepoint.com/bind-javascripts-this-keyword-react/