# IntelliJ shows this.props is undefined while console.log suggests otherwise

Tags: javascript, reactjs, intellij-idea, webstorm, mobx

I have a dialog based on material-ui written with React and mobx, I'm pretty new to mobx+react and trying to understand the lifecycle here.

The component looks something like this:

```
@observer
export default class AddDialog extends React.Component {

    constructor(store, props) {
        super(props);
        this.store = store;
    }

    handleClose = () => {
        this.props.store.setOpen(false);
    }

    handleDateChange = (e, date) => {
        this.props.store.setDate(date);
    }

    handleTitleChange = (e, title) => {
        this.props.store.setTitle(title);
    }

    render() {
        const actions = [
            <FlatButton
                label="Ok"
                primary={true}
                keyboardFocused={true}
                onClick={this.handleClose}
            />,
        ];

        return (
            <div>
                <Dialog
                    title="Title"
                    actions={actions}
                    modal={false}
                    open={this.props.store.open}
                    onRequestClose={this.handleClose}
                >
                    <TextField hintText="title?" onChange={this.handleTitleChange}/>
                    <DatePicker hintText="Due date" onChange={this.handleDateChange}/>
                </Dialog>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

And in `App.js` I have a code that looks like this:

```
@observer
class App extends PureComponent {
    render() {
        return (
            <MuiThemeProvider>
                <FloatingActionButton onClick={this.handleOpenAddPromissDialog}>
                    <ContentAdd />
                </FloatingActionButton>
                <AddPromissDialog store={this.props.addPromissStore} open={false}/>
            </MuiThemeProvider>
        );
    }
}
```

When I debug the code, it looks like both the `store` and `props` args that are passed to the constructor are initialized with the values passed in the `render` function.
But when the `handleClose` is called both `this.props` and `this.store` are undefined. I can't understand what I'm missing here.

**Edit:**
I tried printing the variables to the console, and there they don't appear as undefined but populated as I would expect. So it looks like and IntelliJ issue.

That's the debug configuration I'm using:
[image]

Comment: just running thru basic scenario/questions: is your project defined as a static web project? did you run `npm install` to get all dependencies? maybe go through the checks outlined in their help to see if something is missing: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/react.html#starting_with_existing_react_application

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/28388530/2694656

Comment: @NirWeber not sure the linked issue is related. That one seems to be a Chrome issue - the OP is asking about intelliJ (or webstorm) properties and their auto-resolve ability with reactjs...

Answer (score 3):

the problem is caused by the way Babel transpiles `this` in arrow functions: it is changed to `_this` in transpiled code, and no name mappings are provided:

[image]

You will face the same issue when debugging in Chrome Dev Tools (that use the same API as WebStorm for debugging):

[image]

See [Value of "this" is incorrect when debugging Babel transpiled React with Chrome Devtools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36638663/value-of-this-is-incorrect-when-debugging-babel-transpiled-react-with-chrome-d) and similar reports