# VS code chrome debug, why is this undefined?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I`m using VS code and chrome debugger extension . The code below is executed without errors and produces the expected result, however i see that 'this' is undefined in WATCH section.

```js
class Q {
    constructor() { 
        this.arr = [1,2,3]
    }
    log(e) {
        console.log(e)
    }
    test() {
        this.arr.forEach(e => {
            this.log(e); // this is undefined when debugging
        })
    }
}

const f = new Q().test()
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Sounds like a Watch limitation rather than anything truly concerning. Does the code actually work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Value of "this" is incorrect when debugging Babel transpiled React with Chrome Devtools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36638663/value-of-this-is-incorrect-when-debugging-babel-transpiled-react-with-chrome-d)

Answer (score 7):

To avoid conflicts with the `this` JavaScript keyword, TypeScript renames `this` into `_this` when transpiled. Try watching for `_this` instead.

Comment: This is certainly true, but it is inconvenient to set a watch on _this all the time when I want to see a variable value by hovering the mouse pointer. Any workaround to allow that?

Comment: @Mike Witt: I don't know of any workaround to my workaround. Sorry

Comment: Thanks Bernard that worked, however linting does still complain with `cannot find name _this.ts (2304)`. Do you know how to overcome that?

Comment: To answer my own question add `let _this = this;` before referencing `_this`

Answer (score -2):

```typescript
class Q {

  arr = []

  constructor() { 
     this.arr = [1,2,3]
  }
  log(e) {
     console.log(e)
  }
  test() {
     this.arr.forEach(e => {
         this.log(e);
     })
  }
}

const f = new Q().test()
```