# this is undefined inside sfc vue method

Tags: vue.js, google-chrome-devtools

My problem is the following:
while hovering over the variable while debugging inside the chrome devtools this is what I´m getting:

[image: dev tools image]

In the devtools console:
[image: console print]

Anyone has any idea why this would be happening? This is really anoying since makes the debugging process much more troublesome!!!
Any solution?

Comment: More info needed. Care to show the actual function where that is happening?

Comment: Probably same as [Value of "this" is incorrect when debugging Babel transpiled React with Chrome Devtools](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36758179)

Comment: @wOxxOm.... thanks for the reply... I´ll give a shot and check if this is related to transpilation. The project is, in fact, using babel. I´ll try to disable it and see the results

Comment: @wOxxOm... yes... I´ve disabled babel in the dev environment and now it´s working fine... thanks a lot...God bless you!

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to access variable `_thisN` where `N` is 1 or 2, 3 ... in the console instead, which is provided by the Babel transpiler.

I think this is related to an optimization technique Chrome uses to clean up variables outside of scope. See [Why does Chrome debugger think closed local variable is undefined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28388530/why-does-chrome-debugger-think-closed-local-variable-is-undefined) for further explanation.